# Entity Framework 6.1 - Code-First One-to-Many on single entity: Can't map PK to FK?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I'm trying to do a One-to-Many on a single table/entity using code first. My entity looks like this and works fine:

```
public class StockIndex
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [StringLength(45, MinimumLength = 3)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [StringLength(500)]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public List<Component> Components { get; set; }

    public StockIndex ParentStockIndex { get; set; }
    public List<StockIndex> StockSubIndices { get; set; }

    public StockIndex()
    {
        StockSubIndices = new List<StockIndex>();
    }
}
```

It creates a table with a PK and FK, like you'd expect:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[StockIndex] (
    [Id]                  INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Name]                NVARCHAR (45)  NULL,
    [Description]         NVARCHAR (500) NULL,
    [ParentStockIndex_Id] INT            NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.StockIndex] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.StockIndex_dbo.StockIndex_ParentStockIndex_Id] FOREIGN KEY ([ParentStockIndex_Id]) REFERENCES [dbo].[StockIndex] ([Id])
);
```

It works great. I've scaffolded all the CRUD for it and everything works. However, this forces me to fire an additional query in my controllers when doing an edit, in order to lookup and assign a "parent" record to the new one. I want access to the "ParentStockIndex_Id" field in table so I can assign it directly from a dropdown and skip the extra lookup query. I tried mapping it:

```
public class StockIndex
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [StringLength(45, MinimumLength = 3)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [StringLength(500)]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public List<Component> Components { get; set; }

    public int ParentStockIndex_Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ParentStockIndex_Id")]
    public StockIndex ParentStockIndex { get; set; }

    public List<StockIndex> StockSubIndices { get; set; }

    public StockIndex()
    {
        StockSubIndices = new List<StockIndex>();
    }
}
```

But I get an exception when running it, when data is seeded in my DbContext:

Unable to determine the principal end of the 'MyApp.Models.StockIndex_ParentStockIndex' relationship. Multiple added entities may have the same primary key.

I'm sure I'm doing something wrong, but would like to do this without using Fluent, if possible.

Comment: may be `public int? ParentStockIndex_Id { get; set; }`, to set the Parent not required (have you seen the **question mark** just after int).

Comment: @tschmit007 Bah! That was it! I knew I needed to make int nullable too...completely forgot about it. Been away from dotnet for a few years. Thanks! Make sure you post it as the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `public int? ParentStockIndex_Id { get; set; }`, to set the Parent not required (have you seen the **question mark** just after int).